# Matching a sentence in python

Tags: python-3.x

`nba.txt`:

```
Raptors looking for trade #WetheNorth...
```

My code:

```
def nba_tweet(NBA):
  with open('nba.txt','r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if NBA in line:
                match=True
            if match:
                ##some_code
  if not match:
     return []
```

The problem is that if I do `nba_tweet('Raptors looking for trade #WetheNorth..')` it stills works even though one of the period is gone from the text_file. Also, the text file is huge but I just did the displayed the text I'm having problem with NBA is the string from the text file.

Comment: What does "works" mean? What are you passing as `NBA` when you call this? Are you really comparigin it to calling `nba_tweet(Raptors looking for trade #WetheNorth..)` *without quotes*?

Comment: @doctorlove i updated my code and by works i mean like it still displays with the right output even though  its not suppose to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence you have sent to your function to look for is `in` the text in the file, though it is missing the last period.

Notice:

```
>>> sentence = 'Raptors looking for trade #WetheNorth...'
>>> 'Raptors looking for trade #WetheNorth..' in sentence
True
>>> 'Raptors looking for trade #WetheNorth..' == sentence
False
```

`in` wll return `True` if the substring is in the seacrhed string:

```
>>> 'BCD' in 'ABCDE'
True
```

Comment: But the text file has more than 1 line in it, so would it still work

Comment: Your code appears to set `match` to true if it's found. What is does in `##some_code` is not clear, nor is what you return from your function if you do find a match

Comment: okay so in ##some code i return a list that has a hashtag word (with the punctuation and the hashtag symbol) so it would return ['WetheNorth']

Comment: Don't forget to test against `line.strip()` or at least `line.rstrip('\n')`, rather than just `line`. Unless you want to include the `'\n'` character in the search term `NBA` itself.

Comment: @jez you want me to do NBA in line.rstrip('\n') ?

Comment: @CAVS Well, not exactly: as doctorlove's answer says, you want `==` instead of `in`.    So  `NBA==line.strip('\n')`  or `NBA==line.strip()`